# How to join tables with multiple foreign keys and get filtered data in Django?

Tags: python, django

I have two models like this:

```
class Question(models.Model):
        ques_id = models.IntegerField()
        test_id = models.ForeignKey('exam.Test')
        ques = models.TextField()

class UserAnswer(models.Model):
        user = models.ForeignKey('exam.User')
        test_id = models.ForeignKey('exam.Test')
        ques_id=models.ForeignKey('exam.Question')
        user_ans = models.TextField()
```

I need to execute this query to get the correct 'ques' field values.

```
SELECT A.ques_id, B.ques, A.user_ans FROM useranswer A
inner join question B on B.ques_id= A.ques_id and B.test_id =A.test_id
WHERE A.user_id=1 and B.test_id='101'
```

So far what I have done:

```
UserAnswer.objects.filter(test_id=test_id, user_id=user_id).values('ques_id', 'ques_id__ques','user_ans')
```

But it doesn't returning the right 'ques' field values because it doesn't considering the B.test_id =A.test_id section. How to retrieve it???

Answer (score 0):

First of all, your field names are misleading. Do **not**
suffix foreign key fields with `_id`! Accessing them as attributes returns model instances and django provides the `_id` suffixed attributes to access the actual keys implicitly:

```
class Question(models.Model): 
    test = models.ForeignKey('exam.Test')
    ques = models.TextField()
    # is this supposed to be the primary key? Don't do that
    # ques_id = models.IntegerField() 

class UserAnswer(models.Model):
    user = models.ForeignKey('exam.User')
    ques = models.ForeignKey('exam.Question')
    user_ans = models.TextField()
    # This is redundant as ques belongs to a test already
    # test = models.ForeignKey('exam.Test')
```

I assume you want to get all the answers for one user and one test:

```
UserAnswer.objects.filter(
    ques__test_id=test_id, 
    user_id=user_id
).values('ques_id', 'ques__ques', 'user_ans')
```